# How to select an item in drop down list by value using jquery programmatically?

Tags: jquery, select

How to select an item in drop down list using jquery programmatically?

say I have a list with the following options

apple
orange
banana

and it's called `#myList`

How to I select banana manually using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$('select').val('someval').attr('selected', true);
```

takes second item and sets attribute selected

for modern versions of jquery you should use the .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$('select').val('someval').prop('selected', true);
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CWvwn/1763/

Comment: Ditch the `attr` and `prop` - the `.val()` call will take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
$("#myList").val("banana");
```

Pass the `value` of the option you want selected to the `.val()` function.

Comment: I think he means to choose some item

Comment: He want to make item selected